# How to animate inside frame with infinite loop

Tags: html, css

```
    <div className="sound-wave-container py-8">
      <img
        src={!recording ? Wave : DottedLine}
        className={!recording ? "sound-wave" : ""}
        alt="Sound Wave"
      />
    </div>
```

---

```css
.sound-wave-container {
  outline: 1px inset #999;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
}


/* Define the animation */

@keyframes moveRightInfinity {
  0% {
    transform: translateX( 0%);
    /* Start from the left boundary of the container */
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX( calc(100% - 100px));
    /* Move to the right, but stop before it fully exits the view. Adjust the "100px" to the width of your image if it's different */
  }
}


/* Apply the animation to the image */

.sound-wave {
  animation: moveRightInfinity 10s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="sound-wave-container py-8">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" class="sound-wave" alt="Sound Wave" />
</div>
```

currently it it going outside of div. How can i keep that inside frame and needs to continue in right side direction so it will look always full .

Comment: There are no `<frame>` nor `<iframe>` elements in your code. A `<div>` is not a "frame".

Comment: This won't work with div ?

Comment: I've converted your post into a Snippet and it seems to be working fine...

Comment: No. Once it reach to right end it should come smoothly from left end that much.

Comment: Now whole thing starting from beginning

Comment: I don't understand what you're describing, sorry.

Comment: When half of the cat entered in right side those hidden part will show in left side like a circle. Instead of restarting.

Comment: 'ti will always look fll'- does this mean that you want a continuous stream of the same image again and again, so when for example the first image to come in on the animation reaches half way across to the right there will already be the other half of the image to its left?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.sound-wave-container {
  --width: 200px;
  outline: 1px inset #999;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: var(--width);
}

.sound-wave {
  object-fit: cover;
  animation: loop 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes loop {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sound-wave-container py-8">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" class="sound-wave" alt="Sound Wave" />
</div>
```

Comment: There's a button `[Copy snippet to answer]` where you could have run it within the site making it easier for all to see your running answer instead of making us go to a different site . Please see [Introducing Runnable JavaScript, CSS, and HTML Code Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets)

Comment: Good call. Just updated. Thanks Ruan.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want you will need 2 separate images, as the first cannot appear at the left while still at the right. The images need to be positioned `absolute` for them to start from the same point, and ideally out of the container (`-100px` here) so we don't see them until the animation starts. This needs the container to have a height, because absolute positionned elements don't take place and don't extend the container's size.

You can use the same animation if it's well calculated, the animation of the second image is delayed half the total duration. Note that I changed the % to px because % will apply to the size of the image, not the container.

```css
.sound-wave-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

/* Define the animation */
@keyframes moveRightInfinity {
  0% {
    transform: translateX( 0px ); /* Start from beyond left boundary of the container (original position) */
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX( 300px ); /* the half of the animation must be the moment the image starts disappearing to the right for it to loop properly */
  }
  66.6% {
    transform: translateX( 400px ); /* The disappearing to the right (the % is calculated to keep the same speed, eg we need to move 100px, the size of the image, and we moved 300px in 50% -> 50*100/300 = 16.6% to move 100px) */
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX( 400px ); /* stay out of sight for the moment*/
  }
}

/* Apply the animation to the image */
.sound-wave {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100px;
  animation: moveRightInfinity 10s linear infinite;
}
.sound-wave2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100px;
  animation: moveRightInfinity 10s linear  5s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="sound-wave-container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" class="sound-wave" alt="Sound Wave" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100" class="sound-wave2" alt="Sound Wave" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To have the 300px element always 'full' you need a minimum of 3 of the 200px images you have chosen. [Think about what happens when an image is 50px across the element, there needs to be a bit of the image to the left and a bit to the right to fill the gaps].

To make the 'arithmetic' easy this snippet uses 4 copies of the image, and puts them into an inner div inside the 300px element.

It animates this inner div by just 50% of its width so that the animation looks continuous. The inner div is displayed flex so that the images are always on a line.

```html
<style>
  .sound-wave-container {
    outline: 1px inset #999;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
  }
  /* Define the animation */
  
  @keyframes moveRightInfinity {
    0% {
      transform: translateX( -50%);
      /* Start from the left boundary of the container */
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(0%);
    }
  }
  /* Apply the animation to the image container */
  
  .inner {
    animation: moveRightInfinity 10s linear infinite;
    display: flex;
  }
</style>
<div class="sound-wave-container py-8">
  <div class="inner">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" class="sound-wave" alt="Sound Wave" />
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" class="sound-wave" alt="Sound Wave" />
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" class="sound-wave" alt="Sound Wave" />
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" class="sound-wave" alt="Sound Wave" />
  </div>
</div>
```